# Why does Bluetooth UWP app give access is denied during connection

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, rfcomm

I am trying to set-up an rfcomm connection with a mobile device and after that I want to set-up hfp service level connection so that I can call from my windows pc and it gives Failed to get

**Bluetooth device from ID Bluetooth#Bluetooth00:45:e2:a8:f6:90-48:83:b4:17:24:c2: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))**

This error I have already added the **bluetooth** and **bluetooth.rfcomm** capability

This is my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Security.Authorization.AppCapabilityAccess;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.Security.Authorization.AppCapabilityAccess;
        
// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409
        
namespace hfpuwp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public static readonly Guid HFP_Id = new Guid("0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
                
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
             
        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BluetoothDevice BlutooDevice;
            RfcommDeviceService BTService;
            StreamSocket BTSocket;
            DataWriter _writer;
            DataReader _reader;

            DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true));
        
            String xz = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < devices.Count; i++)
            {   
                xz += devices[i].Name+" ";
                //Console.WriteLine(i + "#:    " + devices[i].Name + "    " + devices[i].Id);
                if (devices[i].Name == "OPPO F11 Pro")
                {
                    BTDevice.Text = devices[i].Name + " " + devices[i].Id;
                    try
                    {
                        BlutooDevice = await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(devices[i].Id);
                        var result = await BlutooDevice.GetRfcommServicesForIdAsync(RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(HFP_Id));
                        if (result.Services.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var accessStatus = await BlutooDevice.RequestAccessAsync();
                            BTService = result.Services[0];
                            BTSocket = new StreamSocket();
                            if (result.Services.Count > 0 && accessStatus == DeviceAccessStatus.Allowed) 
                            { 
                                await BTSocket.ConnectAsync(BTService.ConnectionHostName, BTService.ConnectionServiceName,
                                        SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);
                            }
                            //_writer = new DataWriter(BTSocket.OutputStream);
                            //_reader = new DataReader(BTSocket.InputStream);
                        }
                        BTDevice.Text = "Connection Sucessful";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Failed to get Bluetooth device from ID {devices[i].Id}: {ex.Message}");
                        continue; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm, you should use `RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.ObexObjectPush)` for enumeration. Could you please try to sample code from the document?

Comment: i am trying the documentation code but in that code somehow **var service = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(services[0].Id);** always points to null and this is i am using to find devices that supports HFPGateway ** var d2 = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
            RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(
                RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(HFP_Id)));** here HFP_Id is 0x111f @RoyLi-MSFT

Comment: Does `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync` returns valid services? Have you checked  the list to see if it contains the ID of your device?

Comment: yes its there @RoyLi-MSFT

Comment: Then what's the result of RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(Put your id directly)? Is it still null?

Comment: yes it is still null btw i tried running the visual studio by administrator and added the capabilities do i still need to give it bluetooth permission because when i was searching i found out **'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll** means my app doesnt have permissions to access the bluetooth device @RoyLi-MSFT

Comment: Is your Bluetooth device paired?

Comment: yes its paired @RoyLi-MSFT

Comment: Does `RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync` have any error code or it just return null?

Comment: no error null only @RoyLi-MSFT

Comment: Please share more information about your real scenario so the Bluetooth team could try to check it further. 1) What is the Bluetooth device that you are using? 2) Could you please create a blank project, reproduce the issue and then share the project with us?
3) Please use the [Bluetooth trace log tool](https://github.com/microsoft/busiotools/blob/master/bluetooth/tracing/readme.md) to collect logs when you are reproducing the behavior.

Comment: Could you please share more information about this?